# Angular set width of a component as an input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, flexbox

I have a simple angular component.

It is as follows:

```
<div class="k-v-c"
fxFlex
fxLayout = "row" >

    <div class="k-c" fxFlex = "widthOfTable" >
    {{ key | translate }}
    </div>

    < div class="separator" >
    </div>

    < div class="v-c" fxFlex = "widthOfTable" >
    {{ value | translate }}
    </div>

< /div>
```

As you can see, I have the `witdhOfTable` as an input to the component.
Basically what I want to do is to set the `fxFlex` of the component as `witdhOfTable` input provided to the component.

This is the code that I have currently and it is not working.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem here is `widthOfTable` is not a static component. To use a dynamic expression, you should use the box-notation to specify the 1-way DataBind (to an expression) like `[fxFlex]="widthOfTable"`

Comment: I see. Then in that case if the `widhtOfTable` is 25 and I want to treat it as 25% how do I do that?

Comment: The default integer value corresponds to percentage.

Comment: So the input has to be a number and not a string. Gotcha!